# Understanding the Term Algebra

Tags: definition, universal-algebra

For fun, I was surveying a little universal algebra from Burris' and Sankappanavar's "A Course In Universal Algebra" (http://www.cs.elte.hu/~ewkiss/univ-algebra.pdf). Definition 10.1 says...

> Let $X$ be a set of (distinct) objects called *variables*. Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a type of algebra. The set $T(X)$ of *terms of type* $\mathscr{F}$ *over X* is the smallest set such that
>
> 1) $X \cup \mathscr{F}_0 \subseteq T(X)$
>
> 2) If $p_1,...,p_n \in T(X)$ and $f \in \mathscr{F}_n$ then the "string" $f(p_1,...,p_n) \in T(X)$

The type $\mathscr{F}$ is just a nonempty set of operation symbols $f$, each with assigned arity, and the subset $\mathscr{F}_n \subseteq \mathscr{F}$ consists of the $n$-ary operation symbols.

Here's my problem. The quotes in his definition around the word *string* are the authors' quotes, not mine. But the authors don't use the word *string* anywhere in the book until that very definition, so though I have an intuitive understanding of what they mean, I have no technical definition to go off of.

As I understand it, a string is just a finite sequence in some alphabet. So I constructed my own term algebra using some equinumerous copy $\hat{X} \cong X$ that was disjoint from the type $\mathscr{F}$, creating two distinct formal parentheses $[\![\,,]\!]$ not contained in $\hat{X} \cup \mathscr{F}$, and then considering the free monoid over the alphabet

$$\hat{X} \cup \mathscr{F} \cup \{[\![\,,]\!]\}$$

and managed to get pretty far with it - even begin to talk about universal mapping properties. But I would like to know what Burris' and Sankappanavar's definition of "string" is, and how they are constructing the term algebra.

Comment: I think that B&S put quotation symbols around "string" to hint that they are asking **you** to fill in the formal details about what $f(p_1, \ldots, p_n)$ should denote, namely some mathematical object that provides an unambiguous representation of the function symbol $f$ and its arguments $p_i$.

Comment: Hmm. A follow up question I was going to ask was about their definition of a *term function*. Is there perhaps another resource that discusses terms and term functions in more detail you could recommend? (crossing my fingers for a free online resource)

Comment: What's your question about term functions?

Comment: For starters, in the book they write "For $p \in T(X)$ we often write $p$ as $p(x_1,...,x_n)$ to indicate that the variables occurring in in $p$ are *among* $x_1,...,x_n$." When they use such notation, do they assume the $x_1,...,x_n$ is a list of distinct variables? It seems like they must, because given an algebra $\mathbf{A}$ of similar type, they define the term function $p^\mathbf{A} : A^n \to A$ to be the projection $(a_1,...,a_n) \mapsto a_i$ in case $p$ is just a variable $x_i$.

Comment: Technically, if $x_1,x_2,x_3 = x,y,x$ and  $p = \sigma(x,\delta(y,x))$ then couldn't I say the variables occurring in $p$ are among $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and write $p(x_1,x_2,x_3)$?

Comment: Sure. But check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_maturity.